# Yaesu ADMS-13 software: open saved file without reading config from radio first?

Tags: yaesu, radio-programming, linux

I recently purchased a Yaesu FTM-6000. I like the radio, and I'm happy that the ADMS-13 software runs under WINE without a problem, but the software has some truly odd behavior and I'm wondering if I'm just missing something obvious.

When you first start the software, it opens an empty document. The "Open..." menu item in the File menu is disabled, so even if you have a saved configuration, you can't open it to edit it/export it/write it to a radio.

After reading the configuration from the radio successfully, the "Open..." item is enabled...so you can discard the configuration you just read from the radio and open a saved version instead.

Is that expected behavior? I generally *don't* want to read the radio configuration; I want to update a saved configuration and then write it out.

This is my first time working with Yaesu software, so I don't know if this is expected/typical behavior or not.

Comment: Definitely bugged. I use the file from a backup to open one.